# How to create web-services in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, web-services, oop, zend-framework

How to create web services over HTTP REST protocol using Zend Framework?

An example code will be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php

// include zend framework in the include path

function methodname($var) {
echo "Hello world - $var";
}

$server = new Zend_Rest_Server();
$server->addFunction('methodname');
$server->handle();
?>
```

To call this web service, open the URL where you have saved this PHP file with the following arguments

http://www.example.com/index.php?method=methodname&var=Test

which will give output of

```
Hello world - Test
```

Comment: thunk you for your helping...Be in touch you.