# Examples of building a REST API server using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, zend-rest

I'm new to Zend Framework (not to PHP), and I need to create a REST based API using Zend.

I've seen examples using Zend_Rest_Server, however other sources state that that has been deprecated.

I'm unable to find a solid example which shows how I should be building such an API.

Comment: exact duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930146/how-to-create-web-services-in-zend-framework/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Zend_Rest_Server is indeed deprecated since ZF 1.9, you should use Zend_Rest_Controller instead. The following blog posts could be helpful : [Building RESTful Services with Zend Framework](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/228-Building-RESTful-Services-with-Zend-Framework.html) and [Create RESTful Applications Using The Zend Framework](http://techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework).

Answer (score 1):

May be this link would be helpful: [Creating a PHP REST API Using the Zend Framework](http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2009/09/02/creating-a-php-rest-api-using-the-zend-framework/).
This code example support REST data in the format of XML and JSON.

Prerequisites:

```
PHP version > 5
Zend Framework 1.9.2 (at the minimum)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something a little more in details, you can check the book

[Zend Framework 2 Application Development](http://www.packtpub.com/zend-framework-2-application-development/book).

The book explains construction of API oriented system in ZF2, through examples.

At the end of book you get:

- **ZF2 API**
- ZF2 Client side app.

The book has a lot of syntax errors as well as any book for programming, 
but it's only one on the market at this moment.