# Make Zend_Rest_Server return JSON instead of XML using ZF

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, rest

Can Zend_Rest_Server return Json ?
If not, what are the alternatives ( other lib suggestions are ok also)

Comment: Zend_Rest_Server is deprecated, you should use Zend_Rest_Controller et al instead. Also see [Examples of building a REST API server using Zend Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312762/examples-of-building-a-rest-api-server-using-zend-framework/5313068#5313068).

Answer (score 3):

Zend_Rest_Server outputs XML, eventhough not clearly specified in the documentation.

There are some alternatives:

You could leverage the whole MVC architecture given by Zend Framework, thanks to `Zend_Rest_Route` and `Zend_Rest_Controller`.
You will find a complete example here:
http://techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework

Again, the example displays plain string, but using `json_encode`, or `Zend_Json::encode` should return json.

And finally, a complete (advanced) example that use the `ContextSwitch` feature:
http://www.chrisdanielson.com/2009/09/02/creating-a-php-rest-api-using-the-zend-framework/

*(If you need more information on `ContextSwitch` Action Helper, please refer to the documentation.)*

Unfortunately, my limited reputation prevent me from giving you more links, but Google is your friend using some magic words such as `zend rest json` or `zend controller rest json` ...

Comment: Zend_Rest_Server is only working with XML. You can't decide the ouput format.

Comment: After some testing, I have edited my answer as the initial example was not working.  
I have not fully tested it, but the Zend_Rest_Controller and ContextSwitch should (must) be working ...