# RESTws using php + symfony + Zend with response in json format

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am new to symfony and php zend

I am building  RESTws using symfony 1.x and Zend 1.11.6 and PHP

here is my code :

```
routine.yml --

api_highConfidenceHash:
  url:    /api/showList.:sf_format
  class:  sfPropelRoute
  param:  { module: api, action: showList}
  options: { model: showListWS, type: list, method: getDeltaList}
  requirements:
    sf_format: (?:json)   

action.class.php --

 public function executeshowList(sfWebRequest $request) {

        require_once 'Zend/Rest/Server.php';
        $server = new Zend_Rest_Server();
        $server->setClass('showList');
        $server->handle();
    }

showList.class.php --

class showList{
      public function getDeltaList($to,$from){
        return json_encode(array('to'=>$to,'from'=>$from);
       }
```

Calling WS:

```
http://localost:9000/test_debug.php/api/showList.json?method=getDeltaList&to=1341705600&from=1341100800
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<showList generator="zend" version="1.0"><showList><response>{"from":"1341100800","to":"1341705600"}</response><status>success</status></showList></showList>
```

My requirement is to only the json response output without xml tags , i googled a lot but not able to find  solution .
Could you please suggest me how can i reponse Ws with only json output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you use `Zend_Rest_Server`, I think you can make REST webservice without Zend using only symfony.

Here example:

**[REST webservice with symfony](http://di-side.com/di-side/services/web-solutions/rest-webservice-symfony/)**

**[sfRestWebServicePlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfRestWebServicePlugin)**

About your question. I think that `xml` return `Zend_Rest_Server`. You can check question [Make Zend_Rest_Server return JSON instead of XML using ZF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324311/make-zend-rest-server-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-zf), and try use answer. But in comment I read that  `Zend_Rest_Server is only working with XML. You can't decide the ouput format`. So, good luck!

Comment: I have skip Zend and used only Symfony by rendering Json directly thanks for references.